# wildcard ssl certificate on multiple servers

Tags: ssl, debian, apache2.4

I purchased a wildcard ssl certificate from godaddy.  I created the CSR from a windows server and installed the certificate successfully on that server.  I want to install the certificate on a debian apache2 server as well.

- Do i need to create a new CSR from the debian server or can i use the existing certificate?
- How do i install a ssl certificate on debian? I haven't been able to find a good link for debian ssl installation.

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: A certificate is just a file, with an other associated file for the private key, and possible third file for the CA certificate and intermediaries. You just need to copy them to any other server you need. A CSR is only needed before the certificate is issued after which you can delete the CSR it is useless. And any search on "apache2 debian ssl installation" or equivalent here or in a search engine should yield lots of results.

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse a wildcard certificate on multiple server as long as the domains you used it for are on the same level. For example you can have a certificate for *.example.com and use it both for *www.example.com* and *api.example.com* but not for **www.app.example.com**.

To install it, copy the certificate, the key and the ca chain(if any) to a location on the server(for example `/usr/local/ssl`) then update your apache virtualhost config to contain the following lines:

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile path/to/example.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFi path/to/example.key
SSLCertificateChainFile  path/to/example_ca.crt
```

Comment: Thank You.  so i do need to create another CSR to get a .key file?

Comment: No a CSR is only needed to obtain the certificate/key(or reniew them) so only do it once.

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance.  Where does the .key file come from?  I have two files from the ssl authority:  ****.crt and ga_bundle_***.crt.

Comment: It is the private key you used to sign the CSR.

Comment: yes, maybe run dos2unix to it to make sure but it should work fine.